# App Store Connect Operation Error Transporter Issue

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload my app however I keep having this error pop up. I'm not sure what caused it as I didn't really change anything but I can't seem to fix it. It looks like a file is missing. I've tried reinstalling Xcode but that did not resolve anything. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I found a fix. It was actually really simple. I just deleted the file /Library/Caches/com.apple.amp.itmstransporter and the files and all of its components were regenerated correctly when uploading to App Store Connect.

Comment: I was having the same problem. This solution worked for me.